# Show that position vector and velocity vector are orthogonal for any value $t$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\vert \vec r(t)\vert  = c$, where $c$ is a constant for all values.

How do I find that the position vector $\vec r(t)$ and its derivative $\vec r'(t)$ are orthogonal for any value of $t$?

Comment: Hint:  $r(t)\cdot r(t)$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks! I know that I'll have to show that r(t) dot r'(t) = 0. I'm just not sure where to start.

Comment: Well, what is $\frac d{dt} (\vec f(t)\cdot \vec g(t))$?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415404/orthogonal-position-and-velocity-vectors

Comment: f'(t) dot g(t) + f(t) dot g'(t)

Comment: @JoshMorgan That's right. So...put it together with the first thing lulu said...

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen But why would I choose to do r(t) dot r(t) instead of r(t) dot r'(t)?

Comment: @JoshMorgan You're given $r\cdot r = c^2.$ It's your premise. You need to use it to derive your desired conclusion that $r\cdot r' = 0.$ (You also use the unspoken fact that the equation obtained by differentiating both sides of a valid equation is valid.)

Comment: Thank you everyone! I apologize for not knowing Latex, but I'm very new to Stack Exchange. So now would I have to prove that r' = 0?

Comment: No...Just differentiate $\vec r \cdot \vec r=c^2$.  That's what you have information about!

Comment: @lulu I am so new to proving/showing how something is true, I really appreciate you and .@spaceisdarkgreen's help.

Comment: No problem. Can you differentiate $\vec r\cdot \vec r$?

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

We are given that:  $$\vec r\cdot \vec r=c^2$$

In particular, that dot product is constant.  Hence, its time derivative is $0$.  But for any dot product of two vector valued functions we have $$\frac d{dt} \vec f\cdot \vec g=\vec f\,'\cdot \vec g +\vec f\cdot \vec g\,'$$

It follows that $$0=\frac d{dt}c^2=\frac d{dt} \vec r\cdot \vec r = 2\vec r\cdot \vec r\,'\implies \vec r \cdot \vec r\,'=0$$  and we are done.